# Command line printing with a Samba printer requiring authentication

Tags: authentication, smb, lpr

Is there a way to print to a Samba printer requiring authentication by providing the credentials on the command line (e.g., with `lpr`)?

I managed to store the credentials in GNOME Keyring and when I am logged with a desktop session I can print with `lpr`.

Is there a way to either:

- supply the credentials to `lpr`
- authenticate the jobs in the queue

when logging in remotely (SSH)?

**Edit**

I know that it is possible to store a set of credentials for all the users (directly in CUPS in the printer URI), but we need each user to authenticate with his/her own credentials.

Comment: It doesn't ue pritcap?

Comment: @mikeserv printcap to do what?

Comment: you can start keyring without gnome or display manager. to do this: eval $(/usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --start --components=gpg,pkcs11,secrets,ssh)
# You probably need to do this too:
export GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL GNOME_KEYRING_PID GPG_AGENT_INFO SSH_AUTH_SOCK

Comment: @edvinas.me The keyring gets started but still no improvement

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### smbclient

You can use `smbclient` to print files. I'm able to print via Samba to one of my printers like so:

```
$ smbclient -U <user> //server/printer -c "print <filename>"
```

#### Example

```
$ smbclient -U sam //bart/mfc-8480dn -c "print hello_printer.txt"
Enter sam's password: 
Domain=[BUBBA] OS=[Unix] Server=[Samba 3.0.33-3.39.el5_8]
putting file hello_printer.txt as hello_printer.txt (0.2 kb/s) (average 0.2 kb/s)
```

### lpadmin

I also found this example here in a thread titled: [Lion Kerberos printing](https://jamfnation.jamfsoftware.com/discussion.html?id=4075). There are 2 methods.

#### Method #1 - Printers already installed

```
$ sudo lpadmin -p PRINTERNAME -o auth-info-required=negotiate
```

#### Method #2 - Adding printer

```
$ sudo lpadmin -p PRINTERNAME -E -v smb://PRINTSERVER/PRINTQUEUE \
    -m Generic.ppd -L "LOCATION" -o auth-info-required=negotiate
```

In either case once you've run one of the above commands you should be able to do `lpr -P PRINTERNAME` after configuring the SMB printer.

**NOTE1:** You may be able to add usernames & domains to the `smb://` line if needed. I did not test that facility however. Also the `-U <username>` switch allows for overriding your username.

**NOTE2:** This method will create a printer with the credentials cached, which may not be what you want, but will allow `lpr` to send prints to a SMB printer, just without the credentials included.

#### References

- [Chapter 10. Printing from the Samba OReilly book](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/using_samba/ch10.html)

Comment: This will allow to setup authentication from the command line but the problem is that when printing from the command line `lpr` has no way to authenticate. The jobs will just remain stuck in the queue.

Comment: @Matteo - see updates.

Comment: `smbclient` works like a charm. Thanks for the update.

Comment: @Matteo - I flipped the methods around so that smbclient is 1st since that's really the A to your Q, but left the `lpadmin` details in in case someone wants to create a more permanent SMB printer entry.

Comment: NOTE! The smbclient version given above prints assuming the file is a text file. If you print a PDF with this, your printer will spew out page after page after page of PDF source code.

Comment: Wonderful answer, smbclient works perfectly. Note that you may have to change your domain in the smb.conf (/etc/samba/smb.conf)